# alguien sabe que tipo de dato se utiliza para guardar una potencia de estaforma 10⁶ en sql server?

Tags: sql, server

Quiero  guardar unidades de  medida como este x10⁶/µL  pero al ingresarlo a la bd se guarda de tal forma x 10 6/ µL sin que aparezca la potencia de esta forma 10⁶,. Quiero saber si se puede  guardar de tal forma
solo he intentado con varchar y nvarchar y nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tu pregunta es como guardar un numero grande? o a que te referis?

Comment: La pregunta no es clara, si es una potencia de 10^6 deberías intentar un tipo numérico adecuado no?, no entiendo porque intentas usar varchar y nvarchar. Quizá debas revisar la documentación sobre [tipos de datos numéricos] (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/numeric-types?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @EJS la pregunta es para almacenar el símbolo de la potencia.

Comment: quiero  guardar unidades de medida como este x10⁶/ µL  pero al  guardarlo se guarda de esta  forma x 10 6/ µL

Comment: Muy bien por editar, se entiende un poco mejor. Me temo que no existe un tipo de datos que te permita almacenar en BBDD fórmulas tal cual. El varchar o nvarchar te puede valer pero para indicar exponentes debes usar el acento circunflejo (^), ya que a modo de 'superíndice' creo que ni siquiera existen números mayores a 3 para los sistema de codificación de caracteres (ASCII, UNICODE, Ansi,...).

Answer (score 2):

En base de datos puedes utilizar nvarchar.

El tema de la codificación siempre es complejo, pero con un nvarchar deberías de poder representar cualquier carácter. Incluidos los de las formulas.

Un ejemplo utilizando una aplicación desarrollada con windows forms.

En la base de datos me creo una tabla con una sola columna de tipo nvarchar

```
Create table dbo.MisChars (columna nvarchar(4000));
```

Ahora me creo una aplicación de windows forms con c#, que contiene un formulario con una caja de texto. A la misma le pego los caracteres que extraigo de codificaciones utf8 y utf16.

[image: Windows Forms1]

De manera que tengo un formulario con un cuadro de texto y se visualizan los superindices, y otros caracteres elegidos un poco al azar.

En tiempo de diseño, le he pegado los caracteres al textBox1

[image: Textbox1]

El código del formulario, solo contiene su constructor, y dos métodos, uno para cada botón. En el primero, guardo en la tabla lo que tiene el textBox. En el segundo recupero lo que tiene, y lo presento en el textBox2

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ConnectionString = @"data source=.; database=HowTo; integrated security=true;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        string consulta = "Insert into dbo.MisChars (columna) values (@texto);";
        //Inicializa el comando que se va a ejecutar
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@texto", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ConnectionString = @"data source=.; database=HowTo; integrated security=true;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        string consulta = "Select top(1)columna from dbo.MisChars;";
        //Inicializa el comando que se va a ejecutar
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, connection))
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            string texto = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            textBox2.Text = texto;

        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, y pulso el botón 1 se guarda en la base de datos, y cuando pulso el botón2 se recupera presentando el mismo resultado.

[image: Resultado]

Del mismo modo, si ejecuto una query en la base de datos directamente, también los puedo visualizar.

[image: Select bbdd]

Comment: ya pude guardarlo muchas  gracias por  su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Bueno Logre  guardar las potencias. y es con el  tipo de dato nvarchar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error era  mío ya que no  cambie  el tipo de  dato en el procedimiento almacenado insertar y actualizar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y  en codigo tambien

string Rpta = " ";
SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
try
{
SqlCon = Conexion.getInstancia().CrearConexion();
SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand("prueba_insertar", SqlCon);
Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

```
            Comando.Parameters.Add("@idsubexamen",SqlDbType.Int).Value = Obj.IdSubexamen;
            Comando.Parameters.Add("@nomprueba", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Obj.nomprueba;
            Comando.Parameters.Add("@unidadDeMedida", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Obj.unidaddemedida;
            Comando.Parameters.Add("@valoresReferencia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Obj.valoresdereferencia;
            Comando.Parameters.Add("@valoresReferencia2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Obj.valoresdereferencia2;
            Comando.Parameters.Add("@valoresReferencia3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Obj.valoresdereferencia3;
            Comando.Parameters.Add("@valoresReferencia4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Obj.valoresdereferencia4;
            Comando.Parameters.Add("@precio", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Obj.precio;
            SqlCon.Open();
            Rpta = Comando.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "Ok" : "Nose pudo  ingresar el  registro";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Rpta = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {

            if (SqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open) SqlCon.Close();
        }
        return Rpta;
```

Comment: El código va como texto por favor